# Simple pure css slide out button in a table row

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a simple slide out button within a table.
I am very bad with CSS and I have been failing miserably for few hours now.

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rpjfhs4v/5/) with relevant code.**

This is the html for a last `td` in a table:

```
<td class="actions">
  <div class="actions-menu-box">
    <a>x</a>
    <ul>
      <li>copy</li>
      <li>paste</li>
      <li>run</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</td>
```

I am hiding and showing `ul` via react using `visibility` property. Clicking on the link changes a state and it sets `visibility` to visible, hidden. That bit works and only thing I really need to figure out now is how to get this guy to line up.

One of my failed attempts:

```
td.actions{
    width: 80px;
    text-align: center;
}
.actions-menu-box{
    a {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position:relative;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    ul{
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        margin: 0px;
        right: 80px;
        padding: 0px;
        border-left: 1px solid #999999;
        background-color: #fafafa;
        li{
            list-style-type: none;
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 10px 10px;
        }
    }
}
```

This is how it is aligning at the moment, top link was clicked:

[image]

How I would like it to show up is to cover the corresponding row and align nicely.

I kind of understand why it is like this but I have been fighting it with different settings for position absolute and relative...

Can someone please point me in to the right direction, maybe a tutorial online? 
No sliding is required at this moment I need to understand that positioning first.

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue in a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) please ?

Comment: JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rpjfhs4v/

Comment: added fiddle with a relevant stylings. javascript is managed via react but in this case is very simple when you click on the x it displays list(sets the value of visibility to visible)

Comment: Not sure what you're after exactly.  Is this close to it? https://jsfiddle.net/3k8ogvj9/  I added CSS to both `td.actions` and `.actions-menu-box ul`

Comment: Yes it is looking good. I will test it as soon as I will get back home. Make it an answer and if you could explain it that would be a bonus!

Answer (score 0):

Can you make a JS fiddle please. will make it easier to help you, then you can see the solution.

without a fiddle I think your actions-menu-box class should be position: relative. Then the UL will be relative to that TD using top and left you should be able to position the menu in the correct spot.

```
 .actions-menu-box{position:relative; ul {position:absolute;top:0;left:0;}}
```

Add that to your css it should help, then play with the top and left amounts in px to move your menu

Comment: You shouldn't answer unless you have a good reason to believe your solution is correct. If you require a JSFiddle, leave a comment asking for it. I've added one in the comments FYI.

Comment: @Michael Access to the CSS in a jsfiddle demo is not always necessary to find a correct solution.  Sometimes the description is enough to tip off a person as to what the problem is most likely to be, and the user can always delete their answer if their guess is incorrect.  The answer provides a possible solution given the amount of information at the time, which is the important part.